# Morris chart undefined using jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, morris.js

I'm new in web development especially jquery and such. In my code, a morris chart is supposedly seen with data from an ajax request. Below is a code snippet
**HTML**

```
<div id = "node" class = "something">//some divs here</div>
<div id = "myModal role = "dialog">//some divs here again
<div class = "modal-body"><div id = "my_chart"></div></div></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var chart_data = '';
  var div_id = '';

  $(".something").click(function(){
    div_id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : 'test1',
      data : { "node_num" : div_id},
      success: function(data){
        chart_data = data;
        console.log(chart_data);
        $('#myModal').modal();
      },
      error: function(data){
        alert("Something went wrong, please refresh");
      }
    });
  });


  $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#my_chart').empty();
      var chart =  Morris.Area({
        element: 'my_chart',
        data: chart_data,
        xkey: 'time',
        ykeys:['power'],
        labels:['Power(Watts)'],
        pointSize: 2,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true,
        lineColors: ['#1abc9c'],
        fillOpacity: 0.75,
        parseTime: false
        });
      });

  $(".something").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
  })
}); 

</script>
```

***PHP***

```
public function test1()
    {
        $node_num = $this->input->post('node_num');
        $chart = '';
        $chart_data = '';
        $query = $this->Nodes->get_chartdata($node_num);

        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $time = substr($row->n_date, -8);
            $power = ($row->voltage)*($row->current);
            $chart .= "{ power: ".$power.", time: '".$time."' }, ";
        }
        $chart_data = '['.$chart.']';
        echo $chart_data;

    }
```

***PHP OUTPUT***

> [{ power: 21.837696, time: '10:59:41' }, { power: 2.07552, time: '11:00:23' }, { power: 14.09736, time: '11:00:42' }, { power: 10.149408, time: '11:03:52' }, { power: 20.195136, time: '13:45:01' }, ]

supposedly, the morris chart will show a graph [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzxBy.png)(I replaced data: chart_data with the php output). Instead, I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYJAT.png). I followed other methods but it is still the same. Any help on how I can address this? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For chart updation you need to use `setData` .

`chart.setData(chart_data);`

Note :

**1st :** you need to pass the array object to graph not string .

**2nd :** build array in php side and just echo with `json_encode();`

**3rd :** add `dataType:'json',` in ajax call

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you so much! I finally got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @JYoThI, You should check all those points, I would explain one of the step here:

2nd : build array in php side and just echo with json_encode();

OK so in your foreach loop, build an array

```
$array[] = array('power' => trim("Some value"), 'time' => "time here" );
```

Now obviously the above array will return back to ajax success as json data.

```
json_encode(array('newvalue'=> $array), 200)
```

In the ajax success part, just put this line

```
chart.setData(data.newvalue);
```

I used trim while building array, its because I had problem here and once remove spaces it worked fine for me. Hope it helps.